# Question related to Rayleigh quotient

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

This is exercise 12.5 from "Konrad Schmüdgen - Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space".

[image]

This is the whole question and I don't understand it. I think I have some clue about what it was trying to ask (Because this is related to the Min-Max principle and there is also rayleigh quotient for matrices etc.) but in the end, I don't get it.

If you think this is not a good(well written, hard to understand) question. But, you have some clue about what it was trying to ask then please let me know. I would like to solve this...

Comment: I agree, the question *almost* makes sense...

Comment: What is not clear? You should show that $ \|Tx-\lambda x\|$ is minimised for $\lambda = \frac{\langle Tx,x\rangle}{\|x\|^2}$.

Comment: Well, it was not until i saw your comment. Thanks.